# How to recieve a String from a java Server in an objective c client?

Tags: java, objective-c, sockets

I want to read the output of a java server in my objective c client.
in the code below i am able to read but it is only printing the first character of the string sent from the server.

```
 - (void)reading {
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];

   uint8_t buf[1024];
unsigned int len = 0;

len = [inputStream read:buf maxLength:1024];

if(len > 0) {
    NSMutableData* data=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];

    [data appendBytes: (const void *)buf length:len];

    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"hola %@",s);


    }
}
```

on the server side

```
DataOutputStream outToClient=new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
outToClient.writeBytes("mike"+'\n');
```

Comment: Inside the encoding did you try to pass NSUTF8StringEncoding inspite of NSASCIIStringEncoding??

Comment: Still even using NSUTF8StringEncoding, i am not receiving the whole sentence "every time i execute, the sentence received differs like for example if i want to receive sign up accepted you can sign in, sometime it is received as sign up sometime as sign and so on".

Comment: and sorry for my late reply